# Error while grouping variables usuing describeBy function

Tags: r

I am just starting to learn R.
Used function `psych::describeBy` in order to group observation in standard dataset `airquality`.

```
psych::describeBy(airquality, group = df$month)
```

However, got the error message:

> "df$month : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Still, cannot understand what is wrong.

UPDATE:
Ok, this question was my first shot on Stack Overflow. Not particularly successful, but I was doing my best :). Decided not to delete it, in case it may be useful for somebody who is doing his first steps (and to humble myself too).

What I did not realize, when I was dealing with this problem years ago, is that I need to specify my column for grouping using the name of dataset `airquality$Month`, rather than `df$Month`. It was not a spelling issue, but the misunderstanding of syntax basics. I believed that I've already stated that I want to use dataframe named `airquality`, therefore I can address its columns by name `df$Month`, meaning that `df` is a placeholder for `airquality`. Which is totally wrong, of course. However, my intuition was not 100% wrong, in fact this could have been accomplished by using this syntax:

```
psych::describeBy(airquality, group = "Month")
```

You don't need to wrote name of dataframe (because you named it in first argument for function `describeBy`), just need to specify name of column of interest as second argument (as string, therefore in quotation marks).

Also, for some reason I wrote `month`, but correct name of column is `Month` (maybe it was renamed I am not sure).

Hope that my blunder would be a help for somebody else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the issue is with how you're loading/using the dataset. Make sure refer to the dataset in a consistent manner

You can try something like

```
library(psych)
describeBy(airquality, group = airquality$month)
```